# Bonvolu skribi ĉi tiun frazon en simplan esperanton

Tags: meaning

> Temas pri la sekvoj de la fondo de Sennacieca Asocio Tutmonda
> (SAT). (La Klarvido de Hoctor Hodler, en "Esperanto", 1345 (4), Aprilo
> 2020, p77)

Comment: Kio estas simpligenda laŭ vi? Aŭ kio ne kompreneblas?

Comment: Mi ne komprenas ke kiu estas la subjekto de la frazo.

Comment: "La temo estas la sekvoj de la ..."

Answer (score 1):

`temi` estas unu el la [verboj, kiuj ne bezonas subjekton](https://bertilow.com/pmeg/gramatiko/verboj_frazroloj/sensubjektaj.html)

[Jen la klarigo](https://bertilow.com/pmeg/gramatiko/verboj_frazroloj/sensubjektaj.html#i-1rj)

> Temi ne bezonas subjekton, sed havas normale pri-komplementon, kiu
> montras la temon

Leginte tion, kio estis antaŭe menciita:

> Parte tio ŝuldiĝas al la skismo, kiu okazis en 1921, nome al la
> disduiĝo de “neŭ­tra­luloj” kaj laboristoj.

mi supozas ke tiu `temas pri` estas klarigo pri la *disduiĝo*.